# In OpenLDAP what is the difference between cn=config and olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config and when to use which?

Tags: configuration, openldap

I was originally searching for how to make openLDAP reject non-TLS connections, and in the several answers I've found, the configuration changes were made either with

```
dn: cn=config
```

or

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
```

where `hdb` seems to be `bdb` in Apple's Open Directory version.

For example, [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/462958/317270) suggests that one worked and the other doesn't, but it remains a mistery to me what the difference is, and when to use which.

I searched the web, even consulted an OpenLDAP book (!), but was unable to find an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a regular hierarchical config format: `cn=config` is a parent entry that holds global OpenLDAP settings, the `olcDatabase=` child entries hold settings individual to each backend (of which there could be several, e.g. you could multiple hdb instances with different DN suffixes). Some settings can be set in both places, but most of them are only valid in one place or the other.

(`bdb` was the original Berkeley DB backend format and is long obsolete; `hdb` is a much improved version of bdb. But even hdb has already been removed from OpenLDAP 2.6 in favor of the `mdb` LMDB storage backend, so you should migrate.)

Enforcing TLS is better done per-backend, as many clients will make a "rootDSE" query *before* they enable STARTTLS; this is how they query whether the server is *capable* of STARTTLS. The same query is also used to determine supported authentication methods.

Additionally, enforcing TLS may end up preventing local (ldapi://) access, even though it's already secure without TLS.

So I would personally recommend doing this by requiring a minimum `ssf=` (abstract "security strength factor") via per-backend settings, which covers TLS, ldapi, and GSSAPI encryption in one parameter.

Comment: Great explanation. Regarding the TLS configuration, may I ask you to provide an answer to [this other question](https://serverfault.com/q/1129274/317270)?